# Lifestyle of NLog wrapper class

Tags: c#, nlog, simple-injector

I have five different logger and a wrapper class for them :

```
internal class CommonNLogResolver : ICommonLogger
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger commonLog;
    private readonly NLog.Logger errorLog;
    private readonly NLog.Logger dataBaseLog;
    private readonly NLog.Logger logExceptionLogger;
    private readonly NLog.Logger clientLogger;

    public CommonNLoggerResolver()
    {
        commonLog = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.CommonLog);
        errorLog = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.ErrorLog);
        dataBaseLog = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.DBLog);
        logExceptionLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.LogExceptionLog);
        clientLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(Constants.ReportLog);
    }
}
```

I look at the LogFactory.cs in NLog and since it has a cache for logger I don't know what lifestyle is appropriate for my wrapper class.

so my question is should I register this class **singleton** , **transient** or **scope**?

also I'm using SimpleInjector for Dependency Injection.

Comment: As far as I know, NLog is thread-safe, so you can safely reuse your logger. You can make it Singleton.

Comment: Yes Logger instances are thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog is thread-safe, so you can safely reuse your logger. You can make it Singleton.